# Laravel avoid duplication between existing data and new inputs

Tags: laravel

I have an edit form where it shows users, sub-users and I need to make my update method the way that it can update existed sub-users as well as add new ones.

#### Logic

1. User can have a maximum of 5 `sub-users`
2. Let's assume my user `already have 2 sub-users` s/he `can add up to 3 more`
3. I want to be able to update those 2 that are existed already
4. I want to be able to add those 3 new sub-users

#### Code

Here is what I have currently. `Code is commented for better understanding`

```
public function subUsersUpdate(Request $request, $id) {
    $will = Will::where('id', $id)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
    // main user
    $user = User::where('id', $will->user_id)->first();

    // making custom emails for new users like (admin1@example.com)
    // admin is email name of main user, originally (admin@gmail.com)
    // 1~5 are added to names (separate those 5 sub-users)
    // example.com is website domain
    $userMail = substr($user->email, 0, strpos($user->email, '@'));
    $websiteName = env('DOMAIN_NAME');

    // here is what I get from edit form including 2 existed sub-users and 3 new sub-users
    foreach($request->input('subs') as $index => $sub) {
        // trying to separate existed sub-users from new ones
        $existedUser = User::where('name', $sub)->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();

        if($existedUser) {
            // if already existed just update the name
            $existedUser->update(['name' => $sub]);
        } else {
            // if new add them as new sub-user
            $num = $index+1;
            $password = str_random(15);
            User::create([
                'name' => $sub,
                'email' => $userMail . $num ."@" . $websiteName,
                'password' => Hash::make($password),
                'user_id' => $user->id,
            ]);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

#### Error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'admin4@example.com' for key 'users_email_unique'
```

It appears that my code works in order to separate old and new sub-users but the problem is it makes the same email for `new-users` as old ones based on `$num` provided in my `foreach`. I need somehow avoid that duplication.

**Any suggestion?**

#### Update

**What I did**

1. I've added hidden input in my form which has sub-user email as value (if user existed) and if user is newly added it is null.
2. Then I merged those emails array and names array into one
3. Finally I've validate if the email field is null or not in order to update or create new sub-user.

**Issue**

Issue is name of all sub-users will be same as last input (sub-user 5), regardless of user being newly created or updated all 5 get same name!

```
    public function subUsersUpdate(Request $request, $id) {
        $will = Will::where('id', $id)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
        $user = User::where('id', $will->user_id)->first();
        $userMail = substr($user->email, 0, strpos($user->email, '@'));
        $websiteName = env('DOMAIN_NAME');
    
    
        //Changed part
        $mails = $request->input('mails');
        $names = $request->input('subs');
    
        // created array of data
        $finalInputs = [];
        foreach($mails as $index => $mmm) {
            foreach($names as $index2 => $nnn) {
                $finalInputs[$index] = ['email' => $mmm, 'name' => $nnn];
            }
        }
    
        foreach($finalInputs as $index => $sub) {
            if(!empty($sub['email'])) {
                $existedUser = User::where('email', $sub['email'])->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
                $existedUser->update(['name' => $sub['name']]);
                // $userMail2 = substr($sub['email'], 0, strpos($sub['email'], '@'));
            } else {
                if($sub['name'] != null) {
                    $num = $index+1;
                    $password = str_random(15);
                    User::create([
                        'name' => $sub['name'],
                        'email' => $userMail . $num ."@" . $websiteName,
                        'password' => Hash::make($password),
                        'user_id' => $user->id,
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }
        // end of changed parts
    }
```

Comment: Can you specify for what a sub-user is used and what the difference is between a user and a subuser?

Comment: @Aless55 sub-user is a user which has `user_id` column of its master user (you can think of it more like category and sub-category)

Comment: Can you make your scenario work with `updateOrCreate()` instead? It will search for an existing record and update it, otherwise it creates one. Link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts

Comment: @PeterKrebs can you give example based on my foreach to see how it validates for update or create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using updateOrCreate()

`updateOrCreate()` can handle conditional updating or creating of records for you.
This could be what you are asking, hope you get the idea:

```php
foreach($finalInputs as $index => $sub) {
    
    $pwHash = Hash::make( str_random(15) );
    $num = $index+1;
    
    $search = [
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'email' => $userMail . $num ."@" . $websiteName,
    ];
    
    $update = [
        'name' => $sub['name'],
    ];
    
    // Only add 'password' for new users
    if (empty($sub['email']))) {
      $update['password'] = $pwHash;
    }
    
    User::updateOrCreate(
        $search,
        $update
    );
}
```

This will update or create users with the given email address and user-id and create if they don't exist. I don't know how your form works in detail, but I think you can adjust to your exact use-case.

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer but it makes me a bit confused, the logic is 1. If email exist update the name column 2. If email doesn't exist make new user with name-email-password and user_id (refer to my User::create to see the sample) . Is your code doing that or need extra changes?

Comment: My example means, if a `user_id` with that `email` exists, update it. Otherwise create it. Please read the `updateOrCreate` docs as well and understand it, don't blindly trust my code example if it doesn't fit your problem exactly. I'm doing this on the side alongside my regular job.. don't have time to do other people's homework : )